# How can i find all 'friday the 13th' due year 2000 to 2020 by python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i find all 'friday the 13th' due year 2000 to 2020 by python and have it print as below using a nested for loop:

```
print(i,k,13,"is friday the 13th!")
```

ex)

```
2000 10 13 is friday the 13th!
2001 4 13 is friday the 13th!
...
2020 11 13 is friday the 13th!
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: from datetime import date, timedelta


def friday_13_in_year(y):
    day = date(y, 1, 1)
    end = date(y, 12, 31)
    one_day = timedelta(days=1)
    while day < end:
        if day.weekday() == 4 and day.day == 13:
            yield day
        day += one_day

print([str(d) for y in range(2000, 2022+1) for d in friday_13_in_year(y)])

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code in the comments, this should work for you:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def friday_13_in_year(y): 
    day = date(y, 1, 1) 
    end = date(y, 12, 31) 
    one_day = timedelta(days=1) 
    while day < end: 
        if day.weekday() == 4 and day.day == 13: 
            return str(day)+" is friday the 13th!"
        day += one_day 

print([friday_13_in_year(y) for y in range(2000, 2022+1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[i for i in ((datetime.datetime.strptime('20000101','%Y%m%d')+datetime.timedelta(days=i)) for i in range(7306)) if i.day == 13 and i.weekday() == 4]
```

l lists all Fridays 13th from 2000 to 2020. 20 years in days is 20*365.25+1 = 7306